# Firebase function: Request body email variable undefined when using firebase database query

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

In Firebase functions when using a firebase database query, the email variable from the request body gets undefined, but when i hard code the email in the code it works fine.What could be the cause of this issue.

this is the code that i have tried.

```
exports.verify_email_otp = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
   

    response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    
    const email = request.body.email;
    const otp = request.body.otp;
     console.log("email");
     console.log(email);
    const emailList = await admin.database().ref("/email_auth_requests").orderByChild("email").equalTo(email).once('value'); // this line causes the request body data undefined.

    const listData = emailList.val();
    console.log(listData);
    console.log("otp is: ",listData.otp);
    if(listData){
       
      
            if(email){
                if(parseInt(listData.otp) === parseInt(otp)){
                    let userRecord;
                    try{
                        console.log(email);
                        userRecord = await admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email);
                    } catch (error){
                        console.log(error);
                        response.send({ error: "Error finding email" });  
                        userRecord = await admin.auth().createUser({
                            email: email,
                            emailVerified: true
                        });
                    }
                    try{
                        const customToken =  await admin.auth().createCustomToken(userRecord.uid);
                        response.send({ token: customToken });  
                    } catch (error){
                        console.log(error);
                        response.send({ error: "Error creating custom token" });
                    }
                } else {
                    // check.data['count'] = check.data.count? check.data.count + 1: 1;
                    // await admin.database().ref(`/email_auth_requests/${check.key}`).update(check.data);
                    response.send({ error: "OTP mismatch" });
                }
            }else{
                response.send({ error: "Request email not found" });
            }
       
    }else{ 
        response.send({ error: "Request email not found" });
    }
});
```

[image: i am attaching the logs from firebase functions.]

Comment: May I assume that you set CORS headers correctly in the response? However, you may want to consider using the cors package to simplify CORS configuration in your Firebase Cloud Function.

Comment: I have tried to [reproduce your](https://codefile.io/f/oTtnpT6TiF) issue and I am not getting undefined on the email and otp when calling the function from postman through POST request and passing the values as JSON. Perhaps you were trying to send JSON payload through GET request, can you check that again ? If no then please provide more information to solve your issue.

Comment: it works fine with postman, as i comment the line below const emailList = await admin.database().ref("/email_auth_requests").orderByChild("email").equalTo(email).once('value'); the request body has data, but as i un comment this line of code then request body gets undefined. this is the main issue.

Comment: Can you share the exact details on how you call it? E.g. postman screenshot